# How to access nested JSON data | REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, nested-json

I have a problem when trying to fetch one nested JSON object from local API endpoint **/user/{id}** that looks like this :

```
{"userId":122,"name":"kissa","email":"kissa@kissa.com","phone":"04819283921","profile":{"profileId":1,"profileName":"student"}}
```

Everything else works like a charm but when trying to implement **"user.profile.profileName"** it gives me an error when reloading the page:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'profileName')

**User.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import './user.css';

const User = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const params = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/users/" + params.id)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((user) => setUser(user));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="user__container">
      
      <div className="user__table">
        <table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>UserId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Profile</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{user.userId}</td>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
            <td>{user.phone}</td>
            <td>{user.profile.profileName}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default User;
```

Without **{user.profile.profileName}** property the table looks good and every other data is visible.

I tried to fetch data from nested JSON object and excepted it to work like other properties but keys inside profile cant be fetched like other properties.

Comment: Debug the `user` variable, it may not contain the object you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first render, your user is not loaded yet, so `user.profile` is undefined.

So you can either, have an early return while you do not have a user loaded

```
const [user, setUser] = useState();
...

if (!user) return null;
```

Or use the optional chaining in your JSX

```
<td>{user?.profile?.profileName}</td>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! <td>{user?.profile?.profileName}</td> did the trick!